# Making one-sided conclusions from two-sided tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, inference, experiment-design, intuition

I'm reading Montgomery's [Design and Analysis of Experiments](http://faculty.business.utsa.edu/manderso/STA4723/readings/Douglas-C.-Montgomery-Design-and-Analysis-of-Experiments-Wiley-2012.pdf). On page 39, he rejected a two-sided $t$-test against the null hypothesis that modified formulation of some cement mortar doesn't change its bond strength, and then, presumably by noticing that samples from the modified formulation has lower mean, he added

> One can conclude that the modified formulation reduces the bond strength (just because we conducted a two-sided test, this does not preclude drawing a one-sided conclusion when the null hypothesis is rejected).

I don't get it. How can you make a one-sided conclusion from a two-sided test?

Or more generally, can you make any conclusion beyond the alternative on rejecting the null? If so, can I conclude that the expectation of (un)modified cement mortar is exactly the corresponding sample mean?

Comment: You have concluded there's a difference. You can see which direction it was in (which tail your statistic fell into). I am pretty sure this is already answered somewhere on site. [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244492/claim-the-superiority-of-a-treatment-in-the-context-of-a-significant-difference) hits some of the issues but that's not what I am thinking of

Comment: @Glen_b I can get the intuition, but let's suppose instead of two directions, we have a million possible directions. Are you still sure that the direction suggested by the sample mean is the direction where the difference truly lies in?

Comment: You only have two directions in the conditions described in the question. If you want to discuss some other situation, ask specifically about it in the question

Comment: @Glen_b Will do, but the one-million-direction case just serves as an example. I mean, just like the number of random variables, univariate analysis is very different from bivariate analysis, but the latter is not so much different from other multivariate analysis? So I don't think two directions is fundamentally different from one million directions.

Comment: I can't tell if it's different until I understand what you want to know. I imagine it's probably going to be sufficiently clear (enough to be able to generalize) from the bivariate case

Comment: @Glen_b I wonder it's legitimate to draw a conclusion beyond the alternative, i.e. there is a difference. When designing a one-sided test, some prior knowledge must be employed (with the alternative being $\mu > \mu_0$, you implicitly assume $\mu \ge \mu_0$), so I suppose one- and two-sided tests are fundamentally different. How can you come to the conclusion specific to a one-sided test from a two-sided one, which doesn't include any prior knowledge?

Comment: In the univariate case, consider what would happen if you did *two* one-sided tests each at half the significance level (in the usual case where both those alternatives are mutually exclusive)

Comment: @Glen_b I don't that that would be legitimate, because the assumptions behind these tests are conflicting: one assumes $\mu$ cannot be less than $\mu_0$, whereas the other assumes $\mu$ cannot be greater than $\mu_0$. If both assumptions hold true, it means you already know $\mu = \mu_0$ from prior knowledge, eliminating the need for hypothesis testing. As another reason against the practice you proposed, what if both tests give you a reject?

Comment: In the circumstances I suggest, they can't both reject. The discussion by Senn in the link I gave in the first comment discusses the same notion. Please ponder it carefully.

Comment: @Glen_b I see, so the point is to run both tests on the same observation. While I agree that it's impossible to reject both tests, this procedure still doesn't make a lot of sense because of the conflict between their prerequisites. Besides, IIRC running multiple tests on the same observation calls for multiple comparison techniques, which Senn didn't discuss in the quoted section.

Comment: Which pre-requisites? (The null and/or the alternative are not pre-requisites. They're possibilities that are being considered in a particular way)

Comment: @Glen_b I was referring to [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/799479), and the conflict is that different sided test calls for incompatible assumptions. From my understanding, if your alternative is $\mu > \mu_0$, you must already know (presumably from prior knowledge) that $\mu \ge \mu_0$, because you don't care to spare any power on the side $\mu < \mu_0$.

Comment: I don't see a difficulty at all (either with a two tailed test or any number of mutually exclusive alternatives). What particular property of hypothesis tests would no longer pertain?

Comment: @Glen_b I have reflected on it, and realized that my confusion is not from the test itself, but rather from drawing conclusion using the result of a test. DoE is inferential, and presetting a significance level suggests that Neyman-Pearson's test is being used. Trying to make inference with decision theory is the root of the problem, I guess. For the conclusion "there is a difference", this issus is not evident, but it becomes obvious to me when you want to make a subsequent conclusion about the direction of the difference.